# PySpark Dataframe forward fill on all columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, time-series, missing-data

I have the following problem. I have a dataset that keeps track of changes of a status.

```
id  valid  eventdate
 1  False 2020-05-01
 1   True 2020-05-06
 2   True 2020-05-04
 2  False 2020-05-07
 2   True 2020-05-09
 3  False 2020-05-11
```

**Goal**:

```sql
SELECT valid FROM table WHERE id = 1 AND eventdate = "2020-05-05"
```

I need to know at any given date (within the start and today) what the status is for a given day. For example, for `id` 1 valid was still `False` on the 5th of May.

In Pandas I have a solution like this, where I use `pivot` and `ffill` for filling in the empty values. I use a melt to make it back into a three column dataframe.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

test_data = [
  [1,"False","2020-05-01"],
  [1,"True","2020-05-06"],
  [2,"True","2020-05-04"],
  [2,"False","2020-05-07"],
  [2,"True","2020-05-09"],
  [3,"False","2020-05-11"]
]
# Create inputframe
df = pd.DataFrame(test_data, columns=['id', 'valid', 'eventdate'])
df['id'] = df['id'].astype(str)
df['valid'] = df['valid'] == "True"
df['eventdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['eventdate'])
print(df.head(6))
#   id  valid  eventdate
# 0  1  False 2020-05-01
# 1  1   True 2020-05-06
# 2  2   True 2020-05-04
# 3  2  False 2020-05-07
# 4  2   True 2020-05-09
# 5  3  False 2020-05-11

# Create full time range as frame
timeframe = pd.date_range(start=min(df['eventdate']),
                          end=datetime.now().date()).to_frame().reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={0: 'eventdate'})
print(timeframe.head())
#    eventdate
# 0 2020-05-01
# 1 2020-05-02
# 2 2020-05-03
# 3 2020-05-04
# 4 2020-05-05

# Merge timeframe into original frame
df = df.merge(timeframe,
              left_on='eventdate',
              right_on='eventdate',
              how='right')
print(df.sort_values('eventdate').head())
#     id  valid  eventdate
# 0    1  False 2020-05-01
# 6  NaN    NaN 2020-05-02
# 7  NaN    NaN 2020-05-03
# 2    2   True 2020-05-04
# 8  NaN    NaN 2020-05-05

# 1. Pivot to get dates on rows and ids as columns
# 2. Forward fill values per id
# 3. Fill remaining NaNs with False
df = df.pivot(index='eventdate',
              columns='id',
              values='valid')\
       .fillna(method='ffill')\
       .fillna(False)
print(df.head())
# id            NaN      1      2      3
# eventdate                             
# 2020-05-01  False  False  False  False
# 2020-05-02  False  False  False  False
# 2020-05-03  False  False  False  False
# 2020-05-04  False  False   True  False
# 2020-05-05  False  False   True  False

# Drop NaN column and reset the index
df = df.loc[:, df.columns.notnull()].reset_index()
# Melt the columns back
out = pd.melt(df,
              id_vars='eventdate',
              value_name='valid')
print(out.head(10))
#    eventdate id  valid
# 0 2020-05-01  1  False
# 1 2020-05-02  1  False
# 2 2020-05-03  1  False
# 3 2020-05-04  1  False
# 4 2020-05-05  1  False
# 5 2020-05-06  1   True
# 6 2020-05-07  1   True
# 7 2020-05-08  1   True
# 8 2020-05-09  1   True
# 9 2020-05-10  1   True
```

I am trying to achieve the same in Spark, but the forward fill does not exist. I know how to achieve the latest status per `id`:

```py
w = Window().partitionBy("id").orderBy(F.col("eventdate").desc())
df.withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(w)) \
  .where(F.col("rn") == 1) \
  .selectExpr("id", "valid", "eventdate AS last_change") \
  .dropna() \
  .show()
```

Pivoting can be done with:

```py
df\
.select(["id", "valid", "eventdate"])\
.groupBy(["eventdate"])\
.pivot("id")\
.agg(F.min("valid"))\
.drop('null')\
.sort('eventdate')\
.show()
```

To do the forward fill I got this far by limiting the dataset to only one `id`:

```py
import sys
from datetime import datetime
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

test_data = [
  [1,"False","2020-05-01"],
  [1,"True","2020-05-06"],
  [2,"True","2020-05-04"],
  [2,"False","2020-05-07"],
  [2,"True","2020-05-09"],
  [3,"False","2020-05-11"]
]
# Create dataframe
df = sc\
  .parallelize(test_data)\
  .toDF(("id", "valid", "eventdate"))\
  .withColumn("eventdate", F.to_date(F.to_timestamp("eventdate")))\
  .withColumn("valid", F.when(F.col("valid") == "True", 1).otherwise(0))
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
# Create event frame
event_dates = spark.sql("SELECT sequence(min(eventdate), CURRENT_DATE(), interval 1 day) as eventdate FROM df")\
                   .withColumn("eventdate",
                               F.explode(F.col("eventdate")))
# Join dates and data
df = df.join(event_dates, on='eventdate', how='right')

df2 = df.where(df.id == 1)\
  .join(event_dates, on='eventdate', how='right')\
  .withColumn('id', F.lit(1))
#df2.sort('eventdate').show()
# +----------+---+-----+
# | eventdate| id|valid|
# +----------+---+-----+
# |2020-05-01|  1|    0|
# |2020-05-02|  1| null|
# |2020-05-03|  1| null|
# |2020-05-04|  1| null|
# |2020-05-05|  1| null|
# |2020-05-06|  1|    1|
# |2020-05-07|  1| null|
# |2020-05-08|  1| null|
# |2020-05-09|  1| null|
# |2020-05-10|  1| null|
# |2020-05-11|  1| null|
# |2020-05-12|  1| null|
# |2020-05-13|  1| null|
# +----------+---+-----+

# Forward fill
window = Window.partitionBy('id')\
               .orderBy('eventdate')\
               .rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0)
# Set filter
read_last = F.last(df2['valid'], ignorenulls=True).over(window)
df2.withColumn("ffill", read_last).show()
# +----------+---+-----+-----+
# | eventdate| id|valid|ffill|
# +----------+---+-----+-----+
# |2020-05-01|  1|    0|    0|
# |2020-05-02|  1| null|    0|
# |2020-05-03|  1| null|    0|
# |2020-05-04|  1| null|    0|
# |2020-05-05|  1| null|    0|
# |2020-05-06|  1|    1|    1|
# |2020-05-07|  1| null|    1|
# |2020-05-08|  1| null|    1|
# |2020-05-09|  1| null|    1|
# |2020-05-10|  1| null|    1|
# |2020-05-11|  1| null|    1|
# |2020-05-12|  1| null|    1|
# |2020-05-13|  1| null|    1|
# +----------+---+-----+-----+
```

I think the first thing is if this approach to answer the question is the right approach. Doing the `pivot` will create a long table with a few columns, while a lot of redundant data is stored. Spark is not the right tool for the problem, or better, the problem doesn't lend itself to use Spark. I know that ideally you would need to use the parallel processing and perhaps broadcast the `timeframe` to all nodes and calculate the forward fill per `id` per node?

Would it be better to use some different approach, for example, storing the `enddate` of an event and when you query use something like this:

```
id  valid  eventdate enddate
 1  False 2020-05-01 2020-05-06
 1   True 2020-05-06 2999-12-31
 2   True 2020-05-04 2020-05-07
 2  False 2020-05-07 2020-05-08
 2   True 2020-05-09 2999-12-31
 3  False 2020-05-11 2999-12-31
```

and

```sql
SELECT valid FROM table WHERE id = 1 AND "2020-05-05" between eventdate and enddate
```

Please let me know if the Spark approach makes at all, and what is the best way to find the status at any given calendar state for such a sparse dataset?

Thank you.

Comment: what is your spark version?

Comment: I am using Spark 2.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **`spark2.4+`** you can use **`sequence`**, and then **`explode`** it to forward fill. Also I assumed ur date was in this format **`yyyy-MM-dd`**

```
df.show() #sample dataframe

#+---+-----+----------+
#| id|valid| eventdate|
#+---+-----+----------+
#|  1|false|2020-05-01|
#|  1| true|2020-05-06|
#|  2| true|2020-05-04|
#|  2|false|2020-05-07|
#|  2| true|2020-05-09|
#|  3|false|2020-05-11|
#+---+-----+----------+

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w=Window().partitionBy("id").orderBy(F.to_date("eventdate","yyyy-MM-dd"))

df.withColumn("lead", F.lead("eventdate").over(w))\
  .withColumn("sequence", F.when(F.col("lead").isNotNull(),
                                 F.expr("""sequence(to_date(eventdate),date_sub(to_date(lead),1), interval 1 day)"""))\
                                 .otherwise(F.array("eventdate")))\
 .select("id","valid",F.explode("sequence").alias("eventdate"))\
 .show(truncate=False)


#+---+-----+----------+
#|id |valid|eventdate |
#+---+-----+----------+
#|1  |false|2020-05-01|
#|1  |false|2020-05-02|
#|1  |false|2020-05-03|
#|1  |false|2020-05-04|
#|1  |false|2020-05-05|
#|1  |true |2020-05-06|
#|3  |false|2020-05-11|
#|2  |true |2020-05-04|
#|2  |true |2020-05-05|
#|2  |true |2020-05-06|
#|2  |false|2020-05-07|
#|2  |false|2020-05-08|
#|2  |true |2020-05-09|
#+---+-----+----------+
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. I modified it slightly to make the sequence until `current_date()` by replacing the empty `lead` with the current date. 

Would you know how expensive this would get for 10000 ids with a date range of more than a year?

Comment: using explode on sequence at that scale will def not be a small operation but i think it will outerperform the alternative which is to join on a date range with a range of dates in separate df. i think its ur best bet